# Listing the methods, constants, and classes added due to requiring a file

Tags: ruby, class, module, require

Is it possible to list all methods, constants, classes, etc that I can use because of executing `require 'set'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it is hackish, and there is probably no efficient way.

One way is to record the inventory of modules and their constants and methods before and after `require`, and take the difference. Modules can be listed by doing:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).to_a
```

and constants in them can be listed by doing:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module)
.with_object([]){|m, a| a.concat(m.constants.map{|c| "#{m}::#{c}"})}
```

You can do a similar thing with methods. Do this before and after `require`, and take the difference.

Answer (score 0):

To list all [instance methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) of the class:

```
puts Set.instance_methods(false)
```

`Set` class does not define any class-level methods, but whether it did, one might list them:

```
puts Set.methods(false)
```

Passing no/truthy parameter to the methods above will result in printing out *all* the methods of the class, including *derived* from superclasses.

Answer (score 0):

mudasobwa already showed you, how to list methods, defined in `Set`.

Adding few things:

To list singleton methods:

```
Set.singleton_methods # on Ruby 2.3 it returns few => [:[], :yaml_tag]
```

To list constants go with:

```
Set.constants
```

To list subclasses:

```
Set.subclasses # or Set.descendants
```